# MKMapView crash

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview

I could not figure out when exactly crash, because sometimes it happens and most time not. It crash when added new annotation and the pin has dropped down, or when the pin location has changed(drag).

My ios version is 4.3.1

Crash:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3489dc98 objc_msgSend + 16
1   MapKit                          0x336699a4 -[MKMapView mapTileViewDidStartLoading:] + 40
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33589efc -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
3   Foundation                      0x327657a2 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 262
4   CoreFoundation                  0x335f3a72 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
5   CoreFoundation                  0x335f5758 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
6   CoreFoundation                  0x335f64e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
7   CoreFoundation                  0x33586ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
8   CoreFoundation                  0x33586dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
9   GraphicsServices                0x33187418 GSEventRunModal + 108
10  GraphicsServices                0x331874c4 GSEventRun + 56
```

Sorry for my English, thanks in advence

Answer (score -1):

mapTileViewDidStartLoading change this to mapViewDidStartLoading

Comment: Sorry, but I din't understand what you mean:( Actually it crash at this line: [MKMapView mapTileViewDidStartLoading:]. I don't know what kind of method is this (See crash log).

Comment: hey change the function name map mapTileViewDidStartLoading to  mapViewDidStartLoading.because mapTileViewDidStartLoading is really not function in origianal code .so change this